# The Axiom of Choice, and the statement that whenever there is a surjection $A \to B$ there is an injection $B \to A$

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Is there a model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ in which the Axiom of Choice fails but the following statement holds for arbitrary sets $A, B$:

> there is an injection $A \to  B$ if there is a surjection $B \to A$?

Comment: Nobody knows yet.

Comment: I have written many answers on that topic.

Comment: Could you give me a link?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A622+%22partition+principle%22